# Как заполнить базу данных элементами списка?

Tags: c#, база-данных, orm

Пытаюсь заполнить базы данных элементами `List`. Но никак не могу сообразить как это сделать. Код прикрепляю. Помогите пожалуйста, как именно надо поменять код?

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

//Моя модель
namespace parsing
{
    public class Model
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        
        public string? Title { get; set; }

        public string? Price { get; set; }
    }
}

//Создаю базу
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace parsing
{
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

    public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Model> Models => Set<Model>();
        public ApplicationContext() => Database.EnsureCreated();

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=helloapp.db");
        }
    }
}

//То как я пытаюсь заполнить базу
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace parsing
{
    public class DeployData
    {
        public void Deploy()
        {
            using (ApplicationContext context = new ApplicationContext())
            {
                //Сам список взятый из другого класса(Не пустой)
                List<String> pricelist = Parser.arrprice;

                try
                {
                    foreach (string price in pricelist)
                    {
                        Model model = new Model()
                        {
                            Price = price
                        };
                        context.Add(model);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `context.Models.Add(model);`

Comment: `using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
                    {
                        var models = db.Models.ToList();
                        Console.WriteLine("Данные после добавления:");
                        foreach (var m in models)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(m);
                        }
                    }`

Вот так вывожу в консоль что получилось, выводит parsing.Model много раз вместо элементов списка

Comment: Реализация по умолчанию метода `ToString()`, который неявно вызывается у аргумента `m` при передачи в `Console.WriteLine(m)`, возвращает полное имя класса. Переопределите метод `ToString()` у класса `Model` с помощью ключевого слова `override`, чтобы выводило то, что вам надо.

Comment: Дело не в этом, я сейчас проверял на отладчике что он записывает в поле Price, он изначально передает туда parsing.Model

Comment: + база не заполняется

Comment: В свойство `Price` у вас не может записаться ничего, кроме того, что содержится в вашем `pricelist` - проверьте, что у вас лежит в этом списке. Также, возможно вы в отладчике смотрите не свойство `Price`, а саму `Model` (переменную `model`) - а для отображения информации о сущности отладчик также использует тот самый `ToString()`, который я вам предложил переопределить.

Comment: А как его переопределить?

Comment: Список проверил, с ним точно все хорошо

Comment: В классе `Model` напишите метод `ToString()` с использованием ключевого слова `override`, например так: `public override string ToString() => $"Id: {Id}, Title: {Title}, Price: {Price}";`

Comment: Сработало, теперь в консоль все хорошо выводится, но база все равно пустая( Как добавить все это в базу?

Comment: `context.SaveChanges();` делаете же, не удалили? Вероятно, у вас база просто создается не там, где вы ее ищете. Проверьте выходную папку приложения (bin\Debig\...). Как вариант, укажите в `optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=helloapp.db");` полный путь к файлу БД.

Comment: Да. действительно не ту базу открывал. Спасибо Вам огромное! Только единственное у меня на самом деле два поля в Model и два списка. Один список для поля Title, и один список для поля Price. Как мне сделать так что бы в базу данных одновременно загружались данные из обоих списков?

Comment: Если в ваших списках доступны обращения по индексу (в `List<T>` доступно) измените цикл `foreach` на цикл `for` и обращайтесь к спискам по индексу переменной итерации цикла (например, `i`): `Model model = new Model() {Price  = pricelist[i], Title = titlelist [i] };`. Без индексации можно воспользоваться LINQ методом `Zip`, например так: `var models = pricelist.Zip(titlelist, (p, t) => new Model() { Price = p, Title = t });` - это у вас будет готовый список экземпляров Model, который вы можете добавить сразу в контекст БД: `context.Models.AddRange(models);` и cделать `context.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Спасибо большое! А можете пожалуйста написать как будет выглядеть цикл for, на случай если у меня в списках доступны обращения по индексу

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < pricelist.Count; i++) context.Models.Add(new Model() { Price  = pricelist[i], Title = titlelist[i] });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Новые экземпляры сущностей следует добавлять в соответствующий `DbSet<TEntity>` контекста:

```
context.Models.Add(model);
```